# Jetpack Compose Navigation - Bottom Nav Multiple Back Stack - View Model Scoping Issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation, jetpack-compose-navigation

So I have two tabs, Tab A and Tab B. Each tab has its own back stack. I implemented the multiple back stack navigation using code in this [google docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation)

```
    val navController = rememberNavController()
Scaffold(
  bottomBar = {
    BottomNavigation {
      val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
      val currentDestination = navBackStackEntry?.destination
      items.forEach { screen ->
        BottomNavigationItem(
          icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite, contentDescription = null) },
          label = { Text(stringResource(screen.resourceId)) },
          selected = currentDestination?.hierarchy?.any { it.route == screen.route } == true,
          onClick = {
            navController.navigate(screen.route) {
              // Pop up to the start destination of the graph to
              // avoid building up a large stack of destinations
              // on the back stack as users select items
              popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                saveState = true
              }
              // Avoid multiple copies of the same destination when
              // reselecting the same item
              launchSingleTop = true
              // Restore state when reselecting a previously selected item
              restoreState = true
            }
          }
        )
      }
    }
  }
) { 
  NavHost(navController, startDestination = A1.route) {
    composable(A1.route) { 
       val viewModelA1 = hiltViewModel() 
       A1(viewModelA1) 
    }
    composable(A2.route) { 
       val viewModelA2 = hiltViewModel() 
       A2(viewModelA2) 
    }
    composable(A3.route) { 
       val viewModelA3 = hiltViewModel() 
       A3(viewModelA3) 
    }
  }
}
```

Tab A has 3 screens (Screen A1 -> Screen A2 -> Screen A3). I use the `hiltViewModel()` function to instantiate the view model and I invoked it inside the `composable()` block for each screen

The issue is when I'm navigating from A1 to A2 to A3 and then when I change tab to Tab B, the view model for Screen A2 seems like it's being disposed (`onCleared` is called). So when I go back to Tab A displaying Screen A3 then hit back to Screen A2, the view model for A2 is instantiated again (`init` block is called again). What I wanted to achieve is to retain the view model for A2 for this flow until I back out of A2.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a bug when you click on the next navigation item too fast, while the current view appear transition is not yet finished. This is a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/200817333), please star it to bring more attention.

Meanwhile you can wait current screen transition to finish before navigating to the next one. To do so you can check `visibleEntries` variable and navigate only after it contains only single item.

Also I think that current documentation provide not the best example of bottom navigation, because if you're not on a start destination screen, pressing back button will bring you back to the start destination, when I expect the view to be dismissed. So I've changed how you navigate too, if you're fine with the documentation behaviour, you can replace content of `fun navigate()` with your own.

```
val navController = rememberNavController()
var waitEndAnimationJob by remember { mutableStateOf<Job?>(null)}
Scaffold(
    bottomBar = {
        BottomNavigation {
            val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
            val currentDestination = navBackStackEntry?.destination
            val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
            items.forEach { screen ->
                fun navigate() {
                    navController.navigate(screen.route) {
                        val navigationRoutes = items
                            .map(Screen::route)
                        val firstBottomBarDestination = navController.backQueue
                            .firstOrNull { navigationRoutes.contains(it.destination.route) }
                            ?.destination
                        // remove all navigation items from the stack
                        // so only the currently selected screen remains in the stack
                        if (firstBottomBarDestination != null) {
                            popUpTo(firstBottomBarDestination.id) {
                                inclusive = true
                                saveState = true
                            }
                        }
                        // Avoid multiple copies of the same destination when
                        // reselecting the same item
                        launchSingleTop = true
                        // Restore state when reselecting a previously selected item
                        restoreState = true
                    }
                }
                BottomNavigationItem(
                    icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite, contentDescription = null) },
                    label = { Text(stringResource(screen.resourceId)) },
                    selected = currentDestination?.hierarchy?.any { it.route == screen.route } == true,
                    onClick = {
                        // if we're already waiting for an other screen to start appearing
                        // we need to cancel that job   
                        waitEndAnimationJob?.cancel()
                        if (navController.visibleEntries.value.count() > 1) {
                            // if navController.visibleEntries has more than one item
                            // we need to wait animation to finish before starting next navigation
                            waitEndAnimationJob = scope.launch {
                                navController.visibleEntries
                                    .collect { visibleEntries ->
                                        if (visibleEntries.count() == 1) {
                                            navigate()
                                            waitEndAnimationJob = null
                                            cancel()
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                        } else {
                            // otherwise we can navigate instantly
                            navigate()
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
) { innerPadding ->
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the root cause of this. I was using these dependencies and they don't seem to go together.

```
androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha03 

androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha10"
```

I removed the `navigation:navigation-compose` dependency and it seemed to work fine now.